# Trigger pipeline on upstreamProjects for any/all branches of a multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I trigger a downstream project to build when *any* branch or tag of an upstream multibranch pipeline builds?

To build the `master` branch specifically, I have successfully put this in my Jenksinsfile for the downstream project:

```
triggers {
    upstream(upstreamProjects: 'upstream-project/master', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
}
```

But I want my job to run when *any* branch of `upstream-project` builds. How do I do that?

I've tried

```
triggers {
    upstream(upstreamProjects: 'upstream-project', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
}
```

and

```
triggers {
    upstream(upstreamProjects: 'upstream-project/*', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
}
```

Both show errors if I view the "configure" tab of the project, and neither cause the current project to build if e.g. `upstream-project/master` gets built.

In reality, I want to trigger this project when a *tag* for the upstream project has been built (with this [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/basic-branch-build-strategies/)). And I don't know and am therefore unable to declare in the Jenkinsfile what tags will be added in the future. But tags also show up as e.g. `upstream-project/1.2.3` hence this question.

### Don't want to alter the upstream project

I realize that I could change the upstream project and add something like:

```
build job: 'downstream-project', parameters: [
    string(name: 'Foo', value: 'Bar')
]
```

But it is on purpose and by design that I want the downstream project to know about the upstream project and not vice-versa. Otherwise the answer is trivial :-)

### Declarative Directive Generator

The "Pipeline Syntax" → "Declarative Directive Generator" also only seems to suggest individual concrete, existing branches as suggestions.

<kbd>[image: Declarative Directive Generator suggestsions]</kbd>

### Error in "Configure" for downstream project with my attempts:

If I e.g. try to use `pvm-api-service/*` it looks like this if I try to "configure" the pipeline:

[image: pvm-api-service/* shows an error]